Record initialization with multiple constructors?
I'd like to seed my database with an array of records.
All required properties of my record type are to be provided in a constructor, for the programmer to get a hint on which properties are required and not nullable. I also want to provide a default constructor for Entity Framework Core to be able to construct the record type.
One of the properties is a navigation property. I'd like to use lazy loading, so I need to declare it as being virtual. Since it's virtual, I cannot use a primary constructor as it doesn't accept the virtual keyword.
So, I finally came up with a record definition like this:
[PrimaryKey(nameof(Id), nameof(Language))]
public record DataText
{
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  [Length(2, 200)]
  public required string Id { get; init; }

  public required virtual Language Language { get; init; }


  [Length(2, 3000)]
  public required string Text { get; init; }



  public DataText() { }

  public DataText(string id, Language language, string text)
  {
    Id = id;
    Language = language;
    Text = text;
  }

However, when I try to seed my database using an array of the above records like this:
DataText[] texts =
  [
    new DataText($"{nameof(ProfileItem)}.{profileItems[0].Id}", de, "Titel")
  ];

… I'm getting compiler errors CS9035:
CS9035: Required member 'DataText.Id' must be set in the object initializer or attribute constructor.
CS9035: Required member 'DataText.Language' must be set in the object initializer or attribute constructor.
CS9035: Required member 'DataText.Text' must be set in the object initializer or attribute constructor.


I want to keep the constructors as a design decision, and I don't think I can use a primary constructor in this situation … So, how can I get rid of this error?

EFCore doesn't support using record-types as entities: https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/4438 - you'll need to switch back to using good ol' fashioned class types.

Gee … Thank you for this very informative hint! I voted for it, requesting to amend the docs. —– OK then, just out of curiosity, leaving EF Core behind, just focussing on the record data type: how would this situation be coped with considering the record data type alone?

record types are meant to be immutable, but the properties you've declared are get; set;-mutable, so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here...

...why is Language a virtual member when you say you're not using EF anymore?

"All required properties of my record type are to be provided in a constructor, for the programmer to get a hint on which properties are required and not nullable" - You're mistaken here: required has nothing to do with #nullable: they're orthogonal. required means "The set-accessor must be invoked by ctor or object-init" so you can have public required String? Foo (which is required and nullable), public required String Foo (which is required and non-nullable), public String? Foo (which is not required and nullable), and public String Foo (which is req and non-nullable)

@Dai: Thanks for the comment. I updated my property setter to init.

@Dai: I see, yet doesn't the constructor with parameters invoke the set-accessor here?

The public DataText() { } ctor certainly doesn't...

required means that you need set the property in the object initializer. By default, a constructor does not count. You can use the [SetsRequiredMembers] attribute on a constructor if you do want to use a constructor.
Be careful though, this disables the compiler check - You could also set this on an empty constructor and it would allow objects to be created without the properties initialized.
